# Специальный символ это экранированный символ?

Tags: javascript, строки, символы, экранирование

Их разных интернет статей я понял, что...
***Экранирование** - это своего рода процесс/механизм, при котором символ, используемый в коде, переводится в обычный строковый символ и начинает восприниматься как строка.*

А что такое тогда специальный символ? Это любой экранированный символ?

К примеру, является ли `/n` экранированным символом? Как я понимаю, в этом случае это скорее всего просто символ, не экранированный. Потому что вроде бы как экранирование должно заставлять интерпретатор воспринимать конструкции языка как обычную строку. Ну а в данном случае `n` не переводится просто в строку как `/"` или `/'`.

Поэтому возникает вопрос. Что такое экранирование и спец символ? Возможно я неправильно понимаю смысл слова "экранирование", возможно специальные символы - это необязательно все экранированные символы.
Хочется правильно употреблять термины)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специальный символ — довольно широкое и вряд ли точно определённое понятие. Наверное, можно сказать, что любой символ может быть специальным, если его используют не в буквальном строковом значении, а наделяют особым дополнительным смыслом.

Экранирование обычно служит для противоположного — чтобы вернуть специальному символу его обычное строковое значение.

С этой точки зрения, `\n` это специальный символ — или скорее специальное сочетание символов —  для перевода строки, потому что здесь `\` и `n` не означают косой черты и буквы 'n'. Но если мы экранируем это: `\\n`, тогда это сочетание превращается в обычное сочетание косой черты и буквы 'n'.

Точно так же: если кавычки встречаются в строке, они воспринимаются как спецсимвол окончания этой строки. Но если мы их экранируем, им возвращается обычное строковое значение в составе этой строки и они перестают быть спецсимволом.

Можно сказать, что экранированный спецсимвол — это спецсимвол, переставший быть таковым.